# How to update a field in a table on checkbox check in Angular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am having a task where when I check the checkbox, the fields in a database table has to be changed to TRUE (boolean field) and uncheck, it should be FALSE.

Here is my angular html page checkbox code:

```
<checkbox-field attribute='updateExistingItems' label='Update Existing Items'></checkbox-field>
```

And angular/app/src/controllers/file.js:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('myex').controller('FileImportsCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$rootScope', '$filter', '$state', '$timeout', '$confirm', '$stateParams', '$interval', 'User', 'FileImport', 'fileImports', 'APP_SETTINGS', 'Title', '$modal',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $filter, $state, $timeout, $confirm, $stateParams, $interval, User, FileImport, fileImports, APP_SETTINGS, Title, $modal) {

    $scope.updateExistingItems = [];
        FileImport.query().then(function (results) {
        return $scope.updateExistingItems = results;
      });
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);
```

I tried adding in angular controller, but couldn't make it. Please help me how to write oncheck and uncheck code in angular in rails?

Comment: please use [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) for handle check/uncheck event with angularjs. you can check that event by ng-model.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd - my problem is there will be no button click in the html page, it has to be directly changed on checked.

Comment: OK, but did you check given link example. In that example with live data changed by check/uncheck event. There is nothing to use button for handle these event.

Answer (score 1):

As AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd said you need to use ng-change as well as set an ng-model on your checkbox.

```
<checkbox-field ng-change="updateItems()" ng-model="mycheckbox" attribute='updateExistingItems' label='Update Existing Items'></checkbox-field>
```

Additionally you will need to have a function to call with the ng-change in your controller. Like this:

```
$scope.updateExistingItems = [];

FileImport.query().then(function (results) {
  $scope.updateExistingItems = results;
});

$scope.updateItems = function(){
  for( var i = 0; i < $scope.updateExistingItems.length; i++){
    $scope.updateExistingItems[i].checkbox = $scope.mycheckbox;
  }      
}
```

If you need to access the checkbox value you can access it using `$scope.mycheckbox` in your controller.

Comment: this ng-model="mycheckbox" has to be placed anywhere else like, because it is not affecting anywhere and when I give $scope.mycheckbox, it is not showing value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yfm4vN2Vd4mMqkNJwwK5) a plunker.

Comment: UPDATE file_imports SET update_existing_items = TRUE (checked)

or UPDATE file_imports SET update_existing_items = FALSE (unchecked)
How can we write in controller?

Comment: OK i guess you're getting the model initially with the FileImport query and you want to update it with the checkbox. I have edited the answer to show how to change all of the checkbox fields in the updateExistingItems array with your checkbox value. I can't be any more specific that this without knowing more about your application.